# Getting error "ambiguous reference to member subscript" when using Array instead of NSArray

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am getting error like "ambiguous reference to member subscript" in a dictionary which may contains array type values, when I try to access array type values then getting error. 
Please check below code.

```
var occupations = [
"Malcolm": "Captain",
"Kaylee": "Mechanic",
"Layme": ["Engineer", "Docter"] 
] as [String : Any]


occupations["Jayne"] = "Public Relations"
var arrOfLayme = occupations["Layme"] as! Array //getting error here, If I use NSArray instead of array all will work as expacted
print(valueOcc[0])
```

when I used NSArray type this code going well as below line, I want to do in pure swift way, don't want to add Objective-c.

```
var arrOfLayme = occupations["Layme"] as! NSArray
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
var occupations:[String:Any] = [
    "Malcolm": "Captain",
    "Kaylee": "Mechanic",
    "Layme": ["Engineer", "Docter"]
    ]

occupations["Jayne"] = "Public Relations"


var arrOfLayme = occupations["Layme"] as! [String]
print(arrOfLayme)

//More safe
if let arr = occupations["Layme"] as? [String] {
    print(arr)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift** is a strongly typed language, therefore, you can not access to generic containers, like you were able to in **Objective C** with `NSArray`.

You need to explicitly tell the complier, what sort of `Array` are you expecting to be retrieved from the dictionary.

Do the following:

```
import Foundation

// Delcare type next to the variable, not at the end
// Makes the code more readable
var occupations: [String : Any] = [
    "Malcolm": "Captain",
    "Kaylee": "Mechanic",
    "Layme": ["Engineer", "Docter"] 
    ]

occupations["Jayne"] = "Public Relations"

// Safe reading
if let arrOfLayme = occupations["Layme"] as? [String] {
    print(arrOfLayme)
}

// Force casting option 1
var arrOfLayme = occupations["Layme"] as! Array<String>

// Force casting option 2
var arrOfLayme2 = occupations["Layme"] as! [String]
```

Comment: Thanks @dirtydanee